# How would you prove that a Class partitions a certain sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For example
For the collections${A_n}_{n\in\mathbb{R}}$ determine if the collection partitions $\mathbb{R}^2$

[image]

I know this does partition since the intersections of sets is equal to the empty set and this is an equivalence relation but how should i go about proving this?

Comment: You need to prove two things: $(1)$ that each $\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2$ belongs to a set $A_n$, and $(2)$ that the sets $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: so in other words, $\bigcup A_n = \mathbb{R^2}$?

Comment: Yes, that’s equivalent to my $(1)$.

Comment: Yes, though you don't need to word it as such.  Just simply show that for an arbitrarily selected $(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$ that there exists an $\tilde{n}$ such that $(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})\in A_{\tilde{n}}$

Comment: sorry how would you show that $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ is also $\in A_n$, usually i go about it, given x,y in the set then ... also in the other set. should i say $A_n$ for n=$\mathbb{R^2}$